# References in IEEEtran?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I've downloaded the [official IEEE LaTeX template](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html) but am having some trouble adding references in bibtex format.

For instance if I wanted to cite and reference [this article](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2294265), given as:

```
@article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
    author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
    title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
    journal = {Comm. Mag.},
    issue_date = {March 1994},
    volume = {32},
    number = {3},
    month = mar,
    year = {1994},
    issn = {0163-6804},
    pages = {22--33},
    numpages = {12},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
    doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
    acmid = {2294265},
    publisher = {IEEE Press},
    address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
}
```

#### My attempt

1. Created `references.bib`
2. Populated it with the above reference
3. Uncommented the `\usepackage{cite}` from the IEEE template
4. Adding `~\cite{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265}` to a random section
5. Inserting this text just above `% An example of a floating figure using the graphicx package.`

   ```
   \bibliography{references}{}
   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   ```

#### Error

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \end{thebibliography}

?
```

Comment: In the 5th item of your list: the command `\bibliography` takes only one argument (the name(s) of the bib file(s)), not two. Also, be sure to delete all aux files left over from previous compilations of your main .tex file before running latex, bibtex, latex, and latex once more.

Comment: It only takes one argument? - But the [official documentation](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/) said otherwise :\ — Even after deleting all non *.tex *.bib files from that directory I am still getting aforementioned error.

Comment: What you may think is *the* official BibTeX site on the web -- hey, the domain name does say `bibtex.org`, so isn't it by definition official?! -- is in fact *not official*. For one, the site is not affiliated in any way with Oren Patashnik, the creator of BibTeX. Another dead give-away is that the code examples given on `bibtex.org` feature an embarrassing number of errors. Don't be misled by the fact that somebody was able to capture the domain name `bibtex.org`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

General Edit : IEEEtran is just for the author's convenience to get an idea of the approximate end product. The house-style of IEEE is not released and your (journal) article
will be modified by the editors and copy-editors of the publication office. So no need to super tune your article, balance columns adjust biographies etc. when you are submitting the final version. A rough idea of what is what is enough.

Having said that I've removed my previous comment as it might be understood as it's Michael Shell's fault which is something that I would not even think. I'm not happy with IEEE and its workflow, that's about it.

---

First of all, IEEE is really bad with conference style (I should probably say that the `IEEEtran` is getting old pretty fast.) and many conferences encourage their users to download the `ieeeconf` style from various sources. However, the following is not giving me any errors:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
    author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
    title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
    journal = {Comm. Mag.},
    issue_date = {March 1994},
    volume = {32},
    number = {3},
    month = mar,
    year = {1994},
    issn = {0163-6804},
    pages = {22--33},
    numpages = {12},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
    doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
    acmid = {2294265},
    publisher = {IEEE Press},
    address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\title{This document}
\author{This author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
I have cited this document \cite{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes one needs to clear the auxiliary files and recompile again. Initially I got the same error `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` following this answer, however, once I cleared auxiliary files and recompile again it worked fine without changing anything. Great.

Comment: when I tried to upload my pdf file to my conference I received this error `The PDF file has not been certified by PDF eXpress: XeTeX output 2019.01.16:1950` any idea how to overcome that?

Answer (score 8):

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

It can be either due to;

1. Wrong path or name to citation file (*.bib). Note that the file-name or path is **case sensitive** and **without extension**. `\bibliography{./citations}`
2. There is no citation in the text, i.e. `~\cite{}` ... You can temporarily use `\nocite{*}` to print all citations.

P.S. or may be you are using `\ref{}` instead of `\cite{}` ;)

Comment: Citing a paper, compiling the `bibtex`, and then compiling the `tex` file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Actual Reason for this error is...
I found that there are two things that I found are necessary to make the IEEEtran class compile:

1. There needs to be a at least one correct citation in your document one in your bib (in your case, `bibi.bib`) file.
2. In the tool chain, you need to compile with LaTeX (or equivalently PdfLaTeX) **twice**, then once with BibTex, and then with LaTeX again to incorporate the bibliography.

If either of these two things is not the case, I also get the same `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` error. Bizarrely, with a single citation it works for me, but after commenting it out it crashes again.

The apparent reason for this is that the IEEEtran class doesn't like empty bibliographies and can't deal with that. I haven't been able to find an underlying reason for that, though, nor a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`

Before anything, just put the `IEEEabrv` in the folder of your TeX installation. It could be as simple as missing `IEEEabrv` file.

`IEEEabrv` was missing in my TeX installations. You need to download `IEEEabrv` and put it in the directory of your TeX file.

Answer (score 0):

If you cite something like `~\cite{Euzenat10}` in your text but there is no any reference in the corresponding `.bbl` file named `Euzenat10`, then it throws the mentioned error (it may be the cause of misspelling.). When you execute the BibTex command, you can see the message box which citations it couldn't recognize.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) to familiarize yourself further with our format.